# Issue installing sample data Magento2 CE

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I'm trying to install sample data for the luma theme since the front end is empty and there are no categories. But when i run the command

```
composer require magento/sample-data:1.0.0-beta
```

I'm getting the following error in the console

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.0.0].
    - magento/sample-data 1.0.0-beta requires magento/module-sample-data 1.0.0-beta -> satisfiable by magento/module-sample-data[1.0.0-beta].
    - don't install magento/module-sample-data 1.0.0-beta|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.0
    - Installation request for magento/sample-data 1.0.0-beta -> satisfiable by magento/sample-data[1.0.0-beta].
```

Can't seem to get past this and everything in my composer.json looks fine here is the contents of that file.

```
   {
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.magento.com"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-code": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-server": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-soap": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-uri": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-console": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-text": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-i18n": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-view": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-config": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-form": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-di": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-serializer": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-log": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-http": "~2.4.6",
        "magento/zendframework1": "1.12.16",
        "composer/composer": "1.0.0-alpha10",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.16.0",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "1.7.0.3",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "0.1.1",
        "tubalmartin/cssmin": "2.4.8-p4",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
        "braintree/braintree_php": "2.39.0",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3 <2.7",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~0.3",
        "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.0.1",
        "magento/composer": "~1.0.0",
        "lib-libxml": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-spl": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-xsl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.0.6",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-marketplace": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-authorization": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-backup": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-braintree": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-bundle": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-captcha": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-cms": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-cookie": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-cron": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-customer": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-deploy": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-developer": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-dhl": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-directory": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-downloadable": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-eav": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-email": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-fedex": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-gift-message": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-indexer": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-integration": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-media-storage": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-msrp": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-newsletter": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-page-cache": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-payment": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-paypal": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-persistent": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-product-alert": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-product-video": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-quote": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-reports": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-require-js": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-review": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-rss": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-rule": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-sales": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-sales-rule": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-search": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-shipping": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-sitemap": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-store": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-swagger": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-swatches": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-tax": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-theme": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-translation": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-ups": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-user": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-usps": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-variable": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-version": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-webapi": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-weee": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-widget": "100.0.2",
        "magento/module-wishlist": "100.0.2",
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.0.2",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.2",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-de_de": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-en_us": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-es_es": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-pt_br": "100.0.2",
        "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.0.2",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.2",
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.8",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.5",
        "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7"
    },
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php",
            "colinmollenhour/credis": "lib/internal/Credis",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` instead of `composer require`